# Происходит ошибка из-за знака "&" в ссылке

Tags: android, android-sdk

Есть webview приложение, при вставке ссылки с символом  "&" пишет ошибку.
При таких действиях в других исходниках приложений, ошибки не возникает. Как решить? Ссылку заменить нельзя

Comment: Что за ошибка? Почему Вы решили что она возникает именно из-за этого символа?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить на &amp; Если это поможет, то заменяйте все html сущности, потому что есть и другие символы, которые могут вызвать ошибку.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид , android studio выделяет её как ошибку, и не дает скомпилировать apk

Comment: @ilyaplot , а это не повлияет на содержимое ссылок?

Comment: Нет, сущности должны преобразовываться обратно автоматически. Ошибка и возникает из-за того, что сущности преобразовываются, но не являются ими.

Comment: Единственный ответ как раз и показывает как правильно заменить & на &amp;

Answer (score 2):

Побробуйте использовать экранирование символов для ссылки:

```
String strURL = "https://test.com/api/v1?param=1&param=2"; 
strURL = Uri.encode(strURL);
```